# VirtualBox, physical disks, and snapshots

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, snapshot

I have an Ubuntu guest installed on a raw HDD (entire disk, not a partition). It runs just fine under WinXP. In addition, I was able to boot directly into it (using the BIOS boot-device selector).
At some point, I have created a snapshot of the VM. I have made some changes since then.

Today, after a long time, I tried booting into the "VM" disk. It worked, but all the data there is pre-snapshot (or, rather, frozen at the snapshot).

Can I somehow merge the changes since I took the snapshot into the physical state?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to "delete" the snapshot.
See http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=24467